# Is this an ISP, google, or our device issue?

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking

Google drive file preview seems to be slow then I have tried to ping google and yahoo at the same time and this is the result. Is this an ISP, google, or our device problem? Thank you.

[image: image for reference]

Edit:

I tried the tracert google.com and here's the result

[image: tracert]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, unless you are an Autonomous System, I would imagine this is a problem only the ISP can solve.

It might not be their problem (as it might be a problem at Google), but they are definitely the only ones that can start to solve this. The traceroute seems to suggest that the packets disappear at Google's end (72.14.195.168 and 74.125.253.93 are on Google's network) but Google's network operations will not interact with an end-user, so you'd need your ISP to do it in your behalf.

There might be an asynchronous routing/advertising issue, and without more information on the routes/sessions (which you don't have access to), it would be impossible to determine whether this is at the ISP or at Google.

Either way, the end result is the same: you need to contact your ISP.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. I've seen a network advisory from our ISP even though we're far from the area "NORTHER LUZON" this may be causing the issue. 

"Advisory 4: NETWORK UPDATE FOR NORTH LUZON
[28 July 2022, 10:30 a.m. Philippine Standard Time] Some PLDT customers in North Luzon may experience intermittent services as the earthquake that struck the region on 27 July 2022 has caused multiple breaks in one of our international submarine cables servicing the area"